# C#: Iterating the values of the arguments to a function elsewhere in the call stack

Tags: c#, perl

I want inspect the arguments passed to functions higher in my (a?) call stack. In Perl, I would use [Devel::StackTrace](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aStackTrace) to get a stack trace, get the correct frame (a [Devel::StackTrace::Frame](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aStackTrace%3a%3aFrame) object) and from there I would have access to the arguments it was passed.

Anyone know of a way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in .Net.  The closest you can get is to enumerate the current stack frames with the `StackTrace::GetFrames` call.  This will provide you access to the current set of `StackFrame` instances but from there you cannot access the function arguments.

**EDIT**

Based on your comments it sounds like you'd be best served by taking advantage of an Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) library / tools.  As [@ChaosPandion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156142/chaospandion) suggested PostSharp is a popular one.

Comment: I need to be able to capture the arguments to the calling function for logging purposes.

Comment: @rpkelly yeah there's no real great way to do that other than having the method explicitly pass down it's arguments.  There may be a way via an aspect oriented library of achieving this but i'm not terribly familiar with those.

Comment: @rpkelly - You are looking for an AOP framework then. PostSharp is a good option: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/

Comment: Unfortunately that won't quite work, as I have no way to associate the call and return of the same function (which is what I need to do, but getting the return value is easy).

Comment: @rpkelly - What you describe is one of the many reasons AOP frameworks exist. If a framework cannot do what you describe then it certainly is not worth using. Scroll down a bit and you'll see a perfect example: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/monitoring#tracing

Comment: and how do I associate the calls to OnEntry and OnSuccess with the same call stack in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: @rpkelly - I would associate each log entry with the current `System.Threading.Thread.ManagedThreadId`.

Comment: Almost, but that isn't a unique way to identify the current activity.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done using the native API for debugging .NET programs, but not from managed code.

Ok, [MSDN definitely says the CLR debugging API supports this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397953.aspx#examining_program_state):

> You can query a stack frame to obtain the code it is executing or to obtain its arguments, local variables, and native registers.

This looks like the function that does it: [ICorDebugILFrame::GetArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231057.aspx)

Comment: Anybody actually have a working example, anywhere, of this? Can the debugging API be used in C#?

Comment: @vbullinger: I don't see any reason you can't p/invoke it from C#... but a debugger is a separate process.  It'd have to be a different C# application (or maybe a second instance of the same one, but that makes no sense) from the one you're trying to inspect.  For examples, try http://www.google.com/search?q=managed+debugger+written+in+c%23

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full answer but you will want to use what is called Reflection with something like this:
stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod()

I'm sure you can inspect the parameters of the function, but I am not completely certain whether you will be able to get runtime information like the actual values that were passed to the parameters.

Comment: This will only provide you access to the parameter definitions.  It will not provide the arguments for those parameters.

Comment: Indeed, if you don't want just the parameters but the actual runtime values then something like AOP might give you away to create a framework that intercepts values and caches them somehow to be retrieved when needed: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/aspectintercept.aspx

Comment: see also the second page of this post for some AOP examples regarding this same problem: http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/259443-Using-SystemReflection-to-obtain-parameter-values-dynamically?page=2